# Using egrep regex to capture part of line

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to commit git patches via a bash script. This is not a git question! Here is what I want to do, I have a list of files in a directory. I want read those files one by one extract a particular line out of it and then commit.
Here is what I got so far;

```
patches=/{location}/*.patch
for patch in $patches
do
  echo "Processing $patch file..."
  git apply $patch
  git add --all
  git commit -m | egrep -o "(^Subject: \[PATCH [0-9]\/[0-9]\].)(.*)$" $f
  echo "Committed $patch file..."
done
```

Couldn't get the egrep regex working to pass on the proper commit message.
Here is an example line from a patch file;

```
.....
Subject: [PATCH 1/3] XSR-2756 Including ldap credentials in property file.  
......
```

I just want to capture *"XSR-2756 Including ldap credentials in property file."* and use as a commit description to git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU grep, use a Perl look-behind:

```
git commit -m "$(grep -Po '(?<=Subject: \[PATCH \d/\d\].).*') $patch"
```

Comment: Agree. If you're not using GNU grep, use awk instead `awk '{ print gensub(/(^Subject: \[PATCH \d/\d\].)(.*)$/, "\\2", "g") }'`

Comment: `awk '{sub(/^Subject: \[PATCH \d\/\d\]./, ""); print}'` is a little simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `-o` to egrep in this case (since you're matching a bunch of stuff you don't want printed).  Instead, just match the whole line and pipe it to 'cut' (or sed, or something else that will trim a prefix from a line.)

Also, you're piping the output of git commit into egrep, not providing the output of egrep as a command line option to git commit...  I think you want something like:

```
git commit -m "$(egrep '<your regexp here>' $f | cut -d] -f2-)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use sed for this

```
git commit -m | sed -r -n 's#^Subject: \[PATCH [0-9]/[0-9]\] ##p;'
```